# JIRA gadget plugin JAR File

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have the toughest time finding updated information on JIRA, mainly plugin documents. Does any one else have this issue? 
Anyway I was finally created a test plugin and I want to convert it into a JAR file to give it to our JIRA adminstrator to try and do an Add on to our dashboard. I can't find any document that shows how. 
I do see a jar file in the target folder, should I use that?

Comment: I've also had real trouble with this.  I have done the first tutorial but it was fraught with difficulties. Sorry I can't offer any answers (yet) but you are not alone!

Comment: I was able to get several successful gadgets out for our company. Let me know of your issues perhaps I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Set+up+the+Atlassian+Plugin+SDK+and+Build+a+Project and then explore tutorials from there
There's also my book Practical JIRA Plugins (O'Reilly) to help you get started.

And to answer your question, atlas-package and look in the target directory